# How can I show only an arbitrary set of lines of my listing (e.g. lines 1-10 and 15-30)?

Tags: listings

I want to make a listing with a interval, this mwe :

```
\begin[firstline=5, lastline=10]{lstlisting}
<inkscape-extension>
<_name>Export to TikZ path</_name>
<id>net.texample.tools.svg.export_tikz.effect</id>
<dependency type="executable" location="extensions">tikz_export.py</dependency>
<dependency type="executable" location="extensions">inkex.py</dependency>
<dependency type="executable" location="extensions">simplepath.py</dependency>
<dependency type="executable" location="extensions">simplestyle.py</dependency>
<param name="codeoutput" type="optiongroup" _gui-text="Output">
<_option value="standalone">Stand alone</_option>
<_option value="codeonly">Only path code</_option>
<_option value="figonly">Tikzpicture</_option>
</param>
<param name="texmode" type="optiongroup" _gui-text="Text interpretation mode">
<_option value="escape">Escape special TeX chars</_option>
<_option value="raw">Raw TeX</_option>
<_option value="math">Math</_option>
</param>
<param name="crop" type="boolean" _gui-text="Crop">false</param>
<param name="clipboard" type="boolean" _gui-text="Export to clipboard">false</param>
<param name="wrap" type="boolean" _gui-text="Wrap paths">true</param>
<param name="indent" type="boolean" _gui-text="Indent groups">true</param>
<param name="output" type="string" _gui-text="Output filename">none</param>
<param name="verbose" type="boolean" _gui-text="Verbose output">false</param>
<effect needs-live-preview="false" >
<object-type>all</object-type>
<effects-menu>
<submenu _name="Export"/>
</effects-menu>
</effect>
<script>
<command reldir="extensions" interpreter="python">tikz_export.py</command>
 </script>
</inkscape-extension>
  \end{lstlisting}
```

And you will get line code from 5 - 10 , but how to get line code with interval :  firstline = 1, xxline = 4-7, xyline=15-26, and lastline = 33, like this :

```
\begin[firstline=1, xxline=4-7, xyline=15-26, lastline=33]{lstlisting}

\end{lstlisting}
```

And output like this :

```
<inkscape-extension>

<dependency type="executable" location="extensions">tikz_export.py</dependency>
<dependency type="executable" location="extensions">inkex.py</dependency>
<dependency type="executable" location="extensions">simplepath.py</dependency>
<dependency type="executable" location="extensions">simplestyle.py</dependency>

<_option value="raw">Raw TeX</_option>
<_option value="math">Math</_option>
</param>
<param name="crop" type="boolean" _gui-text="Crop">false</param>
<param name="clipboard" type="boolean" _gui-text="Export to clipboard">false</param>
<param name="wrap" type="boolean" _gui-text="Wrap paths">true</param>
<param name="indent" type="boolean" _gui-text="Indent groups">true</param>
<param name="output" type="string" _gui-text="Output filename">none</param>
<param name="verbose" type="boolean" _gui-text="Verbose output">false</param>
<effect needs-live-preview="false" >
<object-type>all</object-type>
<effects-menu>


</inkscape-extension>
```

Comment: Simply use different environments.

Comment: Shouldn't the options go *after*? Like `\begin{lstlisting}[..]`?

Comment: A [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) contain `\documentclass...\begin{document}...\end{document}`, it should compile and contain close to the minimal amount of code needed to explain/demonstrate what you are asking. This saves a lot of time for everyone. It would also be good to explain what "interval" means in this context:)

Comment: Use the `linerange` option of `listings` (described on page 28 of the documentation).

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `listings` package provides the `linerange` option for this kind of operation.

To display line 1, 5-10, 15-16, and 33, use the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=1cm,right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[linerange={1-1,5-10,15-26,33-33}]
<inkscape-extension>
<_name>Export to TikZ path</_name>
<id>net.texample.tools.svg.export_tikz.effect</id>
<dependency type="executable" location="extensions">tikz_export.py</dependency>
<dependency type="executable" location="extensions">inkex.py</dependency>
<dependency type="executable" location="extensions">simplepath.py</dependency>
<dependency type="executable" location="extensions">simplestyle.py</dependency>
<param name="codeoutput" type="optiongroup" _gui-text="Output">
<_option value="standalone">Stand alone</_option>
<_option value="codeonly">Only path code</_option>
<_option value="figonly">Tikzpicture</_option>
</param>
<param name="texmode" type="optiongroup" _gui-text="Text interpretation mode">
<_option value="escape">Escape special TeX chars</_option>
<_option value="raw">Raw TeX</_option>
<_option value="math">Math</_option>
</param>
<param name="crop" type="boolean" _gui-text="Crop">false</param>
<param name="clipboard" type="boolean" _gui-text="Export to clipboard">false</param>
<param name="wrap" type="boolean" _gui-text="Wrap paths">true</param>
<param name="indent" type="boolean" _gui-text="Indent groups">true</param>
<param name="output" type="string" _gui-text="Output filename">none</param>
<param name="verbose" type="boolean" _gui-text="Verbose output">false</param>
<effect needs-live-preview="false" >
<object-type>all</object-type>
<effects-menu>
<submenu _name="Export"/>
</effects-menu>
</effect>
<script>
<command reldir="extensions" interpreter="python">tikz_export.py</command>
 </script>
</inkscape-extension>
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ok , but can i add  different color ?

Comment: @Hirwanto That's different question. What do you want to get colored? `listings` supports syntax highlighting to some degree. Or do you want to colorize the line ranges differenly? That would be more difficult.